# Use Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync to launch Notepad in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am able to launch Microsoft's built-in calculator app through my UWP with

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-calculator:settings"));
```

How can I do the same with an app like Notepad, which isn't one of the default Microsoft apps? I tried converting the exe path to a uri through:

```
var uri = new System.Uri("C:\\\Windows\\\System32\\\notepad.exe");
var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

and then run `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(converted));` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync to launch Notepad in UWP

I'm afraid you can't launch Win32 app with app's path from UWP platfrom. `LaunchUriAsync` only could be used to launch the app that registered [protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#step-1-specify-the-extension-point-in-the-package-manifest).

Currently, there is a workaround that use desktop-bridge to launch desktop extension then call `Process.Start(String path)` to launch Notepad. For more detail please search **UWP with Desktop Extension part 2**.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to escape your `\`s, or prepend the string with an `@`, like this.

```cs
var uri = new System.Uri(@"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"); 
var uri = new System.Uri("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
```

Comment: I was using "\\", but for some reason when I post the question on Stack Overflow it converts them back to "\"